# What are known Linux distros for kids?

Tags: linux

I would not ask which is best as this question would get closed faster that you can say "Linux Distro", but I'll just ask:

What are known Linux distros aimed at kids 6 and under? I know [Edubuntu](http://www.edubuntu.org/) might get suggested but I'm not sure it's aimed at kids this young.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Little girl friendly versions of Linux (or themes for Linux)](http://superuser.com/questions/37408/little-girl-friendly-versions-of-linux-or-themes-for-linux). Also see [How to set-up a Linux machine for children's Internet use?](http://superuser.com/questions/4362/how-to-set-up-a-linux-machine-for-childrens-internet-use) and other related questions.

Answer (score 2):

I know of [Qimo4kids](http://www.qimo4kids.com/) and [Doudoulinux](http://www.doudoulinux.org/web/english/index.html).